# how to force laravel not read the storage files from symlink

Tags: php, laravel

I am hosting my laravel on a Cpanel that not sups symlink so when I run `storage:link` i get this error :

```
symlink() has been disabled for security reasons
```

when I contacted my provider they told me that they can't open it but I have to make changes in my file system to read from the storage itself.
now my question is how can I change the `config/filesystem.php` to not read from symlink but the storage folder itself. thanks in advance

Comment: if you have access to the terminal I would try to run `pwd` and copy absolute path, but there's no guarantee it will work if it's a shared server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options.

If you have access to the command line, you can attempt to manually create the symlink yourself. It's possible they disabled the PHP `symlink()` command, but the OS `ln` command may still be available to you. From the command line:

```
ln -s /path-to-project/storage/app/public /path-to-project/public/storage
```

If you don't have access to the command line, you can attempt to run the command from PHP using one of the program execution methods (`exec()`, `shell_exec()`, etc.). However, if they've disabled `symlink()`, they've probably disabled all of those, as well. To attempt this, create a temporary route, hit it once, then delete it:

```
Route::get('temp-create-link', function () {
    exec("ln -s ".escapeshellarg(storage_path('app/public')).' '.escapeshellarg(public_path('storage')));
});
```

If you don't have a way to run the `ln` command, or if it has been disabled at the OS level, then you'll need to manually create your `public/storage` folder and update your filesystem config to point to it. Once you've created the `public/storage` folder, open your `config/filesystems.php` file and update the `root` key for your public disk to point to it:

```
'disks' => [

    // ...

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        // old value: 'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'root' => public_path('storage'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    // ...

],
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had got this problem when I had used shared hosting. Actually storage:link implementation is not a tough, but you do not have permission to use that command.

1. Create a folder inside public folder. In my case I have created uploads, you can make any folder and sub folders.
2. In Controller, upload file with public_path(). For example purpose I am uploading image.

   ```
     // In html form, file name is cover_image
     if($request->file('cover_image')){
          $image = $request->file('cover_image');
          $extension=$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $file_name = 'File-'.date('Y-m-d-h-i-s').'.'.$extension;
          $destination_path = public_path('/uploads/');
          $result=$image->move($destination_path,$file_name);
          if($result){
             $data['cover_image']=$file_name;
          }
       }
   ```
3. Use asset() to access files. For example purpose I am using img tag.

   ```
   <img src="{{ asset('uploads/'.$item->cover_image) }}">
   ```